# How to filter a lateral view in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Suppose I wish to filter down a huge table with a LATERAL VIEW by using a JOIN.  Example:

```
SELECT things.*
FROM a_few_objects fo join
 (SELECT an_id,
        object.id as object_id,
        object.big_thing
  FROM big_table
  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(outer_things) ot AS outer_thing
  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(objects) o AS object) things
ON fo.objectid = things.object_id
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this than instantiate the "things" subquery (which I think puts on disk a huge table)?

I could put the rows of a_few_objects in the WHERE clause of the inner query, but I want to specify a_few_objects in Hive, so I don't have to change the query all the time.

If I put the join inside the subquery, Hive just gets confused. I'm using Hive 0.13.

Comment: Hi got any solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Hive 0.13 has [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression) (Common Table Expressions).

```
WITH q1 AS ( 
    SELECT an_id,
        object.id AS object_id,
        object.big_thing
    FROM big_table
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(outer_things) ot AS outer_thing
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(objects) o AS object) 

SELECT *
FROM q1
JOIN big_table fo
ON q1.objectid = fo.object_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still instantiates the huge lateral view. I think it's unavoidable.

Comment: the query in the question. i think it is equivalent to your CTE.